# Replace hardcoded variables using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, replace

I've got a script that i would like to make more user-friendly.
At the moment the user needs to manually open the script to replace a few variables that are hardcoded when he/she uses it for the first time.

This ofcourse isn't very user friendly, so i would like to be able to add an option in my script to replace these hardcoded lines while in the script. This way the user can simply run the script and edit the variables in run-time.

I don't want them to just get replaced in memory while the script is running, i want them to actually get replaced in the .sh file, so i can open it up later and see the variables have changed.

I've tried looking around, tried using 'sed' and bash text replacement, but i haven't found what i need yet.

Hope someone here can help me out

Comment: Post your script here to make it a better question.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Heredocs.

```
#!/bin/sh
foo=bar
baz=quux

cat > script.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo $foo
cat "$baz"
EOF
chmod +x script.sh
```